# How to get the max value of a property by grouping on another property in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to figure out how to do the following in neo4j.
I have a result list that looks like this

| ID | Group Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha | Active |
| 2 | Bravo | Active |
| 3 | Alpha | Active |
| 4 | Charlie | Active |
| 5 | Bravo | Active |
| 6 | Bravo | Active |
| 7 | Charlie | Active |
| 8 | Alpha | Active |
| 9 | Charlie | Active |
| 10 | Alpha | Active |
| 11 | Bravo | Active |
| 12 | Alpha | Active |

I want to first group these by group name to conceptually get this.

| ID | Group Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha | Active |
| 3 | Alpha | Active |
| 8 | Alpha | Active |
| 10 | Alpha | Active |
| 12 | Alpha | Active |

| ID | Group Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Bravo | Active |
| 5 | Bravo | Active |
| 6 | Bravo | Active |
| 11 | Bravo | Active |

| ID | Group Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Charlie | Active |
| 7 | Charlie | Active |
| 9 | Charlie | Active |

So that I can then get the max ID from each distinct group and then set the status of all other nodes to inactive except for the node with the max ID of each group so the final result would look like this

| ID | Group Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha | Inactive |
| 3 | Alpha | Inactive |
| 8 | Alpha | Inactive |
| 10 | Alpha | Inactive |
| 12 | Alpha | Active |

| ID | Group Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Bravo | Inactive |
| 5 | Bravo | Inactive |
| 6 | Bravo | Inactive |
| 11 | Bravo | Active |

| ID | Group Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Charlie | Inactive |
| 7 | Charlie | Inactive |
| 9 | Charlie | Active |

My understanding so far has been to do the following in order to get distinct groups to work on

```
match (g: Groups)
WITH g, collect(distinct g.groupName) as names
```

But beyond this I am unsure how to get max status on the group to work. I am not sure if I should alternatively be taking a different approach in neo4j in order to get the result I want and set those node properties for each group.

Comment: what is b in your sample query? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @jose_bacoy I fat fingered the query. I edited to the correct variable

Answer (score 2):

I will do the reverse instead.  Set all status into Inactive then update the status = Active for those groupName with max id.

```
// do a mass update of all groups as inactive
match (n: Groups) set n.status = 'Inactive'
// find the id per group name
with   n.groupName as name, max(n.id) as mx_id
// update the status back to Active
match (g: Groups {groupName: name, id: mx_id}) set g.status = 'Active'
return g
```